# What limitations are there to ByteBuddy's ability to "spread" an Object array over a method's parameters?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am aware of the `MethodCall#withArgumentArrayElements(int)` method.  Briefly, it allows you to accept an `Object[]` and invoke some other method, supplying its parameters in order from the `Object[]` identified by the `int` parameter.  Usually you also use a dynamic assigner.

I am finding an odd limitation where this does not appear to work.  I'd like to understand what I've done wrong or if there is a (rare) problem in ByteBuddy.

I have generated a `static` method using ByteBuddy whose Java code might look like the following:

```
private static final void setFrob(final T target, final Object... parameters) throws Exception {
  target.setFrob((String)parameters[0],
                 (Integer)parameters[1]); // pseudocode; happens via "spreading" mentioned above
}
```

The pattern, as I hope you can see, is that in my instrumented class I define a `private static` setter method named after the "real" setter method (for various reasons).  I take in the `target` and the `parameters`, whatever they might be, and then invoke the "real" setter method on the `target` with the supplied `parameters` array supplying values for the "real" setter method's parameters.  This is not complicated and works fine, **but interestingly only in certain scenarios.**

The method definition's ByteBuddy recipe is:

```
final MethodDescription staticSetterMethod =
  new MethodDescription.Latent(builder.toTypeDescription(),
                               methodToken.getName(),
                               PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_SYNTHETIC_VARARGS_METHOD_MODIFIERS,
                               Collections.emptyList(),
                               TypeDescription.Generic.VOID,
                               List.of(new ParameterDescription.Token(targetType,
                                                                      "target",
                                                                      ParameterManifestation.FINAL.getMask()),
                                       new ParameterDescription.Token(OBJECT_ARRAY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION_GENERIC,
                                                                      "parameters",
                                                                      ParameterManifestation.FINAL.getMask())),
                               Collections.singletonList(EXCEPTION_TYPE_GENERIC),
                               Collections.emptyList(),
                               null,
                               null);
builder = builder
  .define(staticSetterMethod)
```

Because things work in certain scenarios, I've been able to `javap` the resulting class and the method definition is as I would expect.  I'm not worried about this part.

Next, the ByteBuddy implementation recipe looks like this (I've tried to keep it short and relevant):

```
MethodCall.invoke(new MethodDescription.Latent(targetType.asErasure(), // T's actual type
                                               methodToken)) // setFrob(String, Integer)
                     .onArgument(0) // target (of type T)
                     .withArgumentArrayElements(1) // parameters
                     .withAssigner(Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC));
```

…so: "invoke `setFrob`, declared by the type of `target`, described by `methodToken`, on the first argument (`target`) spreading the incoming `Object[]` array values found in the second argument (`parameters`) using dynamic assignment".

My understanding is that if the "real" `setFrob` method needs a `String` and an `Integer` supplied to it, then if the `Object[]` here is two elements long, and if the first element is a `String`, and the second is an `Integer`, then the `withArgumentArrayElements(1)` invocation will ensure that these elements are "spread" "into" the proper method parameters.

Indeed this works fine when the `setFrob` method being called accepts zero or one parameters (let's say it is defined to accept only a `String` parameter).  That tells me that at least my ByteBuddy recipes are correct.

However, I was extremely surprised to note that **it fails when the `setFrob` method being called is changed to accept two parameters.**  The partial stack says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: public void com.foo.bar.TestExplorations$Foo.setFrob(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer) does not accept 1 arguments
        at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:3539)
        at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.apply(MethodCall.java:3508)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:708)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:693)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:600)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5660)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2166)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:232)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:204)
```

The error is resulting from [this conditional](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/03b637778cfa3025b14219a360fe4aa1d2efd920/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L3538-L3540):

```
ParameterList<?> parameters = invokedMethod.getParameters();
if (parameters.size() != argumentLoaders.size()) {
  throw new IllegalStateException(invokedMethod + " does not accept " + argumentLoaders.size() + " arguments");
}
```

The `argumentLoaders` in this case has a size of `1`.  `parameters` has a size of `2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I wonder if there is _actually_ a bug in ByteBuddy here since an `ArgumentLoader` that "spreads" multiple array elements across multiple method parameters will obviously only ever be one loader, but will "expand" to "fill" many parameters.  So I'm wondering if the `MethodCall` conditional I reference above is correct in the case of argument spreaders.

Comment: Aha; interesting. The `withArgumentArrayElements` variant that lacks a `size` parameter is _substantially_ different from the other variants (!), and references a `size` parameter that doesn't exist: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/03b637778cfa3025b14219a360fe4aa1d2efd920/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L408 Lesson: use the 3-argument version; the 1-argument version is misleading: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/03b637778cfa3025b14219a360fe4aa1d2efd920/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L450-L465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer here: It's indeed a bug, the increment was repeated inside the loop. This will be fixed in version 1.10.15.

Comment: Thank you. Do you want me to file a Github issue for tracking purposes referencing this question?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that you *must* use the two- or three-argument variant of [`withArgumentArrayElements`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.13/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#withArgumentArrayElements-int-int-int-) if your receiver method has more than one parameter.  The [one-argument variant](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.13/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#withArgumentArrayElements-int-) seems capable of working only for receiver methods that have zero parameters or one parameter.